# React Native FB SDK handle authentication reject

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I need to handle Facebook login errors in the react-native.

Trying to log in after fresh install of my application shows the popup to the user:

> "Facebook. Application would like to access your basic profile info
>   and list of friends."

with two options: "Don't Allow" and "OK". With normal flow I get a proper token. But if the user rejects in the `onLoginFinished` I get following result:

```
{
  "isCancelled": true,
  "grantedPermissions": null,
  "declinedPermissions": null
}
```

Which has no information about why it was canceled. Is rejection the only reason to get `"isCancelled": true` with `'system_account'`?

After that all the consecutive attempts to login with `'system_account'` instantly fail with following error:

```
{
  "code": "FacebookSDK",
  "domain": "com.facebook.sdk.login",
  "framesToPop": 1,
  "nativeStackIOS": [...],
  "userInfo": {
    "NSLocalizedDescription": "Access has not been granted to the Facebook account. Verify device settings.",
    "com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey": "Access has not been granted to the Facebook account. Verify device settings."
  }
}
```

It gives me the error which I can show to the user but being localized I can not parse it reliably. So the question is how can I reliably detect when the user did not grant permissions?

The code I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import {AccessToken, LoginManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk'

class Login extends React.Component {
    login = ()=>{
        LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('system_account')
        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()
            .then(this.onLoginFinished)
            .catch(this.onLoginError)
    }
    onLoginFinished = (result)=>{
        if(result.isCancelled) {
            //
        } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data)=>{
                this.props.onLogin(data.accessToken.toString())
            })
        }
    }
    onLoginError = (error)=>{
        // Want to handle this case but 
        //can only show a message to the user =(
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.login}>
                    <View><Text>Facebook</Text></View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

From what I can think of I can only make switch to the `'native'` login behavior after receiving cancel with `'system_account'` and handle its behavior separately is it the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using facebook login there is couple of situations to handle.

1. User granted all permissions and logged in
2. User granted some permissions and logged in
3. User not granted any of the permissions and logged in
4. User canceled login attempt

If you check [`LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/67d5e6f3b3c9687d6d4ac103b4c6db722d5c56bb/js/FBLoginManager.js#L74) it uses native code *(for iOS)* [`FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/67d5e6f3b3c9687d6d4ac103b4c6db722d5c56bb/ios/RCTFBSDK/login/RCTFBSDKLoginManager.m#L100) from iOS SDK. In [documentation of iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult/) `isCancelled` is a `BOOL` which shows "Whether the login was cancelled by the user."

So if in your returned result `isCanceled` is true, it means user is canceled the login request manually. This can be because user changed his/her mind or a mis-click on a button or just because he changed his/her mind when he/she sees the list of permissions you asked for etc.. When you checked and see that `isCanceled` value is true then you can assume that user do not want to login with facebook and you can proceed like that *( redirect to another login method or show a popup that users should login etc.)*.

If a user completes facebook login but unchecked some permission requests (like birthday or likes etc.) the permissions will be shown in `declinedPermissions`. You can check `lenght` of this property and proceed with it as you desire. You can create an object that holds all the error messages that you need to show when any of the permissions declined.

**Example**

```
const permissions = [
  {
    permissionName: 'user_likes',
    errorMessage: 'To give you better results we need your likes'
  },
  {
    permissionName: 'user_birthday',
    errorMessage: 'Would you like to receive a gift from us on your birthday?'
  },
  {
    permissionName: 'user_friends',
    errorMessage: 'We can\'t match you without knowing your friends'
  }
];



// ....
login = ()=>{
    LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('system_account')
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions.map((permission) => (permission.permissionName)))
        .then(this.onLoginFinished)
        .catch(this.onLoginError)
}

onLoginFinished = (result)=>{
    if(result.isCancelled) {
        // user canceled login manually
    } else {
        if (result.declinedPermissions && result.declinedPermissions.lenght > 0) {
          // handle declined permissions
          result.declinedPermissions.forEach((declinedPermission) => {
            // match the declinedPermission with the permission object
          }
        } else {
          // user gave all the permissions
        }
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data)=>{
            this.props.onLogin(data.accessToken.toString())
        })
    }
}
```